# Using existing database in aws-cdk while creating a glue table

Tags: python, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I am trying to create one database table in the existing database using aws-cdk in python.

Comment: Can you update your question with what ever you tried ? and error details if any?

Answer (score -2):

Please Refer to [Boto3 python SDK for Glue Client Create Table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_table).

### CDK Reference

**Aws Glue CDK Tables**

Please check Static method [from_table_attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_glue/Table.html#aws_cdk.aws_glue.Table.from_table_attributes)

Comment: If this answer helps you then please upvote/accept it, or edit your question to add enough description about the problem you are facing.

Comment: The question is how to do the same using CDK.